# What is the right way to check if data exists in a Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase I have recently added Firebase authentication to my app.
I have a separate table for Users in my Firebase database.What I want to do is check if the user table has a user with a particular UID.
If the user exists I want to check if the user status is Enabled or Disabled.This is my Users table:-

[image]

Here the Key is the UID from the authentication table.This is my code to check if the user exists.

```
    private boolean checkIfUserExists(final String userId){

        // Get a reference to our posts
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("status")) {


                    isAvailable = true;
                }else{

                    isAvailable = false;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });

        return isAvailable;
    }
```

This is where I call the check if the user exists code.

```
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
//                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, user.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (checkIfUserExists(user.getUid()))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }else{
                                addNewUser(user.getUid(),user.getDisplayName(),user.getEmail(),userStatus);
                            }

                            if (checkUserStatus(user.getUid()))
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }else {
                                DisableProgress();
                                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Please contact ACK to activate your account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

Code for adding a new User.

```
  private void addNewUser(String userId, String name, String email, String 
  status) 
  {
User user = new User(userId,name,email,status);
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

}

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is not bad: you're loading the node for the specific user, and then in client-side code check for their status.

One small improvement would be to move the entire check for the user's status into a query:

```
private boolean checkIfUserExistsAndHasStatus(final String userId){

    // Get a reference to our posts
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);
    Query query = ref.orderByChild("status").startAt("-");

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                isAvailable = true;
            }else{
                isAvailable = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });

    return isAvailable;
}
```

This uses a bit less bandwidth, since it only loads the status node. While it isn't much, every bit may help. :-)

Comment: I did not understand what startAt("-") does.I would like to check if the status is Enabled or Disabled.I have one more problem with my code when I try logging in the 2nd time it resets the status to Disabled.I think the addNewUser() gets called again.

Comment: You can check for a specific value with `ref.orderByChild("status").startAt("Enabled")`. It cannot check for multiple discrete values however, i.e. no `Enabled OR Disabled`. The closest you can get is with a range-query: `ref.orderByChild("status").startAt("Disabled").endAt("Enabled")`

Comment: Thanks but it always returns false in my case even if the user exists in the table. I am using  Query query = ref.orderByChild("status").startAt("Enabled"); Also, the user needs to be added in case the user does not already exist.